# ionic 2 android http error status 0

Tags: android, angularjs, http, ionic2

I have built an Ionic 2 application which calls an API on my own website. On IOS device everything is ok but on Android, I get an error with the code 0. With `ionic serve` I don't have any error (after disabling cross-origin restrictions).

I added the cordova-plugin-whitelist with this configuration :

```
    <access origin="*">
    <allow-navigation href="*">
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*">
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*">
    [...]
```

And on server side I changed the response header in the symfony controller with :

```
 $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

however, I always have an error with status 0 only on Android. What is wrong?

Thank you for your answers!